# Geometric Representation of Complex Expression

Tags: complex-numbers

Here is the question - [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14NZv.png)

I have already worked it out algebraically but was never taught how to answer it geometrically & after watching a few YouTube videos and taking the question literally I came to this answer, is this correct it seems too simple... -

[image: Answer]

This is my newest attempt after following what Henry has said, my reason for having 3i was because I assumed that 1+i was equivalent to 1+1i so if I added 2 to 1i I'd get 3i? - [New attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Tpl.png)

Final edit this seems to be the correct answer -
[image: Final Attempt]

Comment: The locus of points $\,z\,$ at constant distance $\,2\,$ from fixed point $\,1+i\,$ is $\,\ldots\;$

Comment: I am unable to read your full comment

Comment: That *is* the full comment, the $\,\ldots\,$ dots are yours to fill in. What is the locus of points in the plane at constant distance from a fixed point?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad yes the locus of points that Henry commented seem to make sense - 3+i,1+2i,−1+i,1−i

Comment: `1+2i` This point is not on the circle because $\,|(1+2i)-(1+i)|=|i|=1 \ne 2\,$.

Comment: Yess that's what I was thinking but I wasn't using your subtraction method but it should be 1+3i as that equals 2, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments:

- The circle should pass through $3+i, 1+3i, -1+i, 1-i$ rather than $3,3i,-1,-i$
- I would say explicitly that $|z-(1+i)|$ means the distance between any point on the curve $z$ and the point $1+i$ is $2$, and this implies that the curve is a circle centred at $1+i$ of radius $2$